# what is the best approach for developing a game to support all iphone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing a game for Iphones using latest Xcode.
Whatever images and image positions i used in the game seems to work only for a certain device sizes. 
What is the best way to develop a game that suits for all Iphone sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build scalable sprites and images which should keep set proportions. Once you have built a function or two measuring the size of the device and working out a percentage based value you can re-use it all over the game to keep the best quality on whichever device is in use. I have some code to this effect available, just let me know if you need it and I will post away ;)

```
-(int)percX :(int)oldX{
double perc = oldX*100/320.0;
int newX = (deviceWidth*perc)/100;
return newX;
}
-(int)percY :(int)oldY{
double perc = oldY*100/568.0;
int newY =  (deviceHeight*perc)/100;
return newY;
}
-(int)percH :(int)oldH{
double perc = oldH*100/568.0;
int newH =  (deviceHeight*perc)/100;
return newH;
}
-(int)percW :(int)oldW{
double perc = oldW*100/320.0;
int newW =  (deviceWidth*perc)/100;
return newW;
}
```

Okay so these are the functions that calculate the percentage based on the device Proportions. I have used a template device of 320 X 568 but you can obviously change it to suit. Then you just call these when ever you need to set a position for something eg :

```
UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([self percX:56], [self percY:30], [self percW:208] , [self percH:96])];
```

So I would normally look at a screen on the 320 X 568 device in IB and get an idea of where I want the item and then afterward change the code to the percentage values. This scales very nicely across all devices but you will need to check and fine tune if something doesn't quite match up and adjust accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will be helpful for me if you can post some sample code..

Comment: Thank you, If we replace 320 with actual screenwidth and 568 with actual screen height, will it work for all devices.                                                                               EX: CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];                screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
screenWidth =screenRect.size.width;

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind this is only for one orientation. If you want both then you will need to get more sophisticated, eg build separate functions for that mode and apply them or refine these functions to accomodate both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unity 3d

Reasons to use Unity (from [unity3d.com](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/mobile)):

1. Unity is the only major engine built explicitly to be easy for small teams to use
2. As the only leading middleware designed from the ground up to support rapid iteration and on the fly editing, Unity cuts development times drastically in the rapidly moving mobile marketplace.
3. The Unity engine is unique in enabling deployment to the full range of major current mobile ecosystems: iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8 and BlackBerry 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Xcode Auto Layout feature. Go and check [Apple Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) or watch this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk) for brief intro.